# app:mergedebugresources > -1 android studio

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgNbi.png)Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> -1 this is the following error which i am getting during building of project.

Comment: Do not link to screenshots with code. Edit your question and add code and error message as well formatted code please. And to the upvoter: please do not honor such kind of input!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

- This may caused by the path length restriction. Move the project to outer directory and the build will succeed.
- Check if you have correct `gradle` version installed in `build.gradle`

Comment: how will i able to check the correct version of gradle

Comment: @ManthanVaghani. Here is the [Build dependencies documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html)

Comment: Have you tried relocating project to other location? Did it worked?

Comment: @ManthanVaghani Please post the code for manifest and build.gradle and logcat error.